# Is the Selflet system used for any active research?

Tags: dc.distributed-comp

Is the Selflet system (referenced in this paper - http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1365562.1365597 for example) still seeing active research?

Comment: Have you emailed the authors? They would be most likely to know the answer.

Comment: As a starting point you can use citeseer (or other similar websites) to search of recent papers citing that paper.

Comment: I am not sure if this is really a TCS question? If I understood correctly, the concept of SelfLets seem to be more closely related to software architectures.